# How to add devices to the LineageOS github repo?

Tags: custom-roms, kernel, lineageos, builds

My phone isn't currently supported by lineage, and many other phones that either my friends or I have. So I would like to know, how to add a new device tree and kernel for any self-builder to use out there.

Comment: So do you have such a repo locally you made yourself as a dev, or are you just a regular user looking for support?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to visit the [Community](http://lineageos.org/community/) page of LineageOS, which will guide you on how to contribute to LineageOS. If you are a developer, then this page will send you to [Gerrit](https://review.lineageos.org) to do online code reviews about LineageOS.

Once you are familiar enough with how LineageOS works, you can actually go to [GitHub](https://github.com/lineageos) and contribute until you are confident enough to ask to be a member of LineageOS' team.

Then, you can create a new repo under LineageOS' name which will use the codename of the device you want to add and start developing on it.